# Should the panels be fields inside the frame?

Tags: java, field, panel, frame, concept

I created a frame with almost 20 panels inside (all with different kind and characteristics) simply creating them and adding them to the content Panel and remembering his order number for accessing them.

But now I'm trying to generate an UML diagram from the source code and I noticed that i don't have any reference to this panels inside the frame. Should I create 20 field panels and reference them one by one? Or It's just fine? I don't know the right way, thanks!

P.S: I don't know if this matters but my language is Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you write about your panels (*all with different kind and characteristics*) I suspect that these panels also have different classes.

So to access a specific panel your code probably looks like

```
((MyPanelType1) getContentPane().getComponent(0)).someMethod();
```

whereas with fields for every panel

```
private MyPanelType1 firstPanel;
```

the code would look like

```
firstPanel.someMethod();
```

Now decide which code is easier to read, and decide accordingly.

Comment: Yes, and different atributes too, so maybe it's not a good choice to create fields for them. I only wanted to know if my way it's the worst but I see it's not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the panels in JPanel[] array so you can call them any time.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestClass {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JPanel[] panel_order = new JPanel[20]; // 20 the number of panels you have

//generating the panels
public static void main(String[] args){     
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);

    for(int i=0;i<panel_order.length;i++){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        // you can set the panel's location like:
        panel.setBounds(20*i, 0, 80, 50);
        //and border if you are making diagrams
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel_order[i] = panel;
        frame.add(panel);
    }
frame.setVisible(true);
    //now you can access your panels by calling panel_order[panel_number];
        //example display the 5th panel's location
        System.out.println(panel_order[5].getLocation());
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i knew I can, my question if is this more correct assigned to fields or this nevermind when you're creating UML diagrams and dessign it?

Comment: It is easier not to assign them. It will work each way. You can do it however you want.